# XML String Android - Unknown ParentNode

Tags: php, android, xml

I have the following xml:

```
<THISVALUECHANGESANDISUNKNOWN>
<TEST></TEST>
</THISVALUECHANGESANDISUNKNOWN>
```

In PHP I can do something like

```
preg_match('~<TEST>([^<]+)</TEST>~i', $xml, $test);
```

But how do I get the value of TEST in android, if the parentnode is unknown?`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is actually pretty easy to do and is described in good detail in the platform docs: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).

```
String xml = "<THISVALUECHANGESANDISUNKNOWN><TEST></TEST></THISVALUECHANGESANDISUNKNOWN>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xml, "", Parser.xmlParser());
String testValue = doc.select("TEST").text();
```